# Open Directory Folder by a click of a button/linkbutton ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to create a Button/LinkButton that allows users to open Windows Explorer to a specific directory. I have seen others use this, but that doesn't work.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "c:\\Documents");
```

I am using c#, I just dont know how to link the path to the button

Comment: Are you sure all your users will be on windows system? Because AFAIK **c drive** is there only on Windows and of-course the late Symbian OS. I would say use just the file upload control. Let users do some tasks

Comment: Yes all my users will be on windows system. And I dont really want users to upload anything, I just want them to be able to view the folder of all the files.

Comment: You mean to say you want your users to see the list of files in a specific folder which is stored on the server using asp.net application. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah I want users to be able to view the folder stored on the server

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't work because it will be executed server side and I assume you want to open the Explorer client side.

Answer (score 0):

To let the users see the list of items(Folders and Files) inside a predefined folder you can use any `data-bound control` like `repeater` or `listview` and bind them to this `datasource`:

```
        var directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Documents");
        var inner_files = directory.EnumerateFiles();
        var inner_directories = directory.EnumerateDirectories();
        List<DataStructure> datasource = new List<DataStructure>();
        foreach (var item in inner_directories)
        {
            datasource.Add(new DataStructure { Name = item.Name, Type = "Folder", ImageUrl = "link to folder Image" });
        }

        foreach (var item in inner_files)
        {
            datasource.Add(new DataStructure { Name = item.Name, Type = item.Extension, ImageUrl = "link to file Image" });
        }
```

here DataStructure is a class

```
    class DataStructure
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Oh Sorry I actually wanted windows explorer to open, and show all the files

Comment: In that case I recommend to give your users a FTP client because its a great deal security hole to allow browser activity to open actual explorer(Other than file upload control) and AFAIK, none of the browsers allow that. So I'm sorry to satisfy you with your query :(